# Windows Forms and Navigation - Visual Basic 2010

Tags: winforms, windows-forms-designer

## Windows Forms and Navigation

I have researched and read many different web articles and books but found no relevant responses to my problem.

Currently I am programming Windows Forms in Visual Studio using VB 2010.
I am in the search of a solution to find if it is possible to communicate between Windows Forms and having them at a consistent size. Some forms need data and others don't need any.
Is there any solution to my problem or am I wasting my time?

Comment: James, did my answer solve your problem?  If so, can you accept it?  If not, can you give me some feedback so that I can refine or correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep a form from being resized, you can set `FormBorderStyle` to a fixed style.  Here's a [similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/96417cf6-4f2b-4089-b811-c6d2ae672ad3) on MSDN forums where they recommend also disabling the maximize button by setting `MaximizeBox` to false on the form.  Also, here's the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx) where non-resizability is documented.  So to achieve consistent size, you would set the initial sizes as you desire and then lock the forms down to prevent the users from resizing.

Also, it is possible to share data between forms, but how to do so is more of a chapter or two in a book than a Stack Overflow answer.  Basically you would share your data objects between forms, which would display and update the objects.  Search around for data binding.  Microsoft has a brief introduction to the subject [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313482).